# Combining these three SQL Queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have developed these three queries, found below, that find the most views, most comments, and most likes that each Article has (an article is defined by both the Content ID and Format). I undersand that Target ID != ContentID and that Format != TargetClass, but I treat them as they are the same thing.

I need to use these three queries to output the top 3 articles that hold the most comments, likes and views, in priority of that order. I'm not exceptionally talented at SQL, so could someone please provide a solution and a mild explanation? If the question needs to be rephrased, please make it clear and I will do so. Cheers.

**MOST VIEWS** (In descending order; with most views being at the top)

```
SELECT ContentID, Format
FROM Content
GROUP BY ContentID, Format
ORDER BY COUNT(View) DESC
```

**MOST COMMENTS** (In descending order; with most comments being at the top)

```
SELECT TargetID, TargetClass
FROM Comments
GROUP BY TargetID, TargetClass
ORDER BY COUNT(TargetID) DESC
```

**MOST LIKES** (In descending order; with most likes being at the top)

```
SELECT ContentID, Format
FROM Likes
GROUP BY ContentID, Format
ORDER BY COUNT(ContentID) DESC
```

**EXAMPLE DATA AND OUTPUT** (As requested)
**TABLE 1:**

```
ContentID| Format  |View|
---------|---------|----|
    1    |Paperback|1700|
---------|---------|----|
    1    |  Ebook  |1500|
---------|---------|----|
    2    |Paperback|1500|
-------------------------
```

**TABLE 2:**

```
CommentID|TargetID |TargetClass|
---------|---------|-----------|
    1    |    1    |   Ebook   |
---------|---------|-----------|
    2    |    2    | Paperback |
---------|---------|-----------|
    3    |    1    |   Ebook   |
--------------------------------
```

**TABLE 3:**

```
  LikeID | ContentID| Format  |
---------|---------|---------|
    1    |    1    |Ebook    |
---------|---------|---------|
    2    |    2    |Paperback|
---------|---------|---------|
    3    |    2    |Paperback|
------------------------------
```

**DESIRED SOLUTION:**

In table 1 contentId = 1 and format = paperback have the most views, BUT, views are weigh less than likes when decided the popularity of an article. In table 3, ContentId=2 and format=paperback, have more likes than either of the other two articles (the one absent from the table has no likes at all). Comments are weighted most heavily however, and in table 2, targetid=1, format=ebook has more comments than either of the other two articles.

This means that targetid=1 and format=ebook is the most popular book. HOWEVER, when two have the same number of comments, they fall back on the likes to determine the most popular article. However, if, once again, they have the same number of likes, it falls back on views to determine the most popular article.

The output required is a list as follows:

```
ContentID | Format
1         | ebook
2         | paperback
1         | paperback
```

In order of their "popularity".

Comment: Do you need total 3 articles that have the most comments, likes,then views. Or do you need 3 articles with most comments, 3 with most likes and 3 with most views?

Comment: @Sev . . . Your question appears to be unclear.  It would help if you had sample data and desired results.

Comment: @Kyborek
Three Content IDs and Formats in total, returned. Im basically just trying to find the top three popular articles present in the database.

Comment: @GordonLinoff
I'll start working on some sample data. However, my aims is to: 
-> Find articles with the most views
and out of those returned 
-> Find articles with the most likes
and out of those returned
-> Find the articles with the most comments.

I'm not entirely sure about the database, because I'm quite new to database development. All I know is that I'm using mysql and phpmyadmin to manage database interaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the correct solution:

```
SELECT V1.ContentID, V1.Format
FROM 
        ((SELECT ContentID, Format ,Sum(View) AS CountView
        FROM Content
        GROUP BY ContentID, Format) V1) LEFT OUTER JOIN 

        (
          SELECT V2.ContentID, V2.Format ,CountComments,CountLikes
          FROM
          ((SELECT TargetID AS ContentID, TargetClass AS Format,Count(TargetID) AS CountComments
          FROM Comments
          GROUP BY TargetID, TargetClass) V2) LEFT OUTER JOIN 

          ((SELECT ContentID, Format ,Count(ContentID) AS CountLikes
          FROM Likes
          GROUP BY ContentID, Format) V3)

          ON(V3.ContentID=V2.ContentID AND V3.Format =V2.Format)
        ) V12
        ON(V1.ContentID=V12.ContentID AND V1.Format =V12.Format)
ORDER BY CountComments DESC,CountLikes DESC ,CountView DESC
LIMIT 3;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need, just in the opposite order. Could you please edit it?

If I take the limit off, it runs exactly how it should but displays the total list from least popular to most popular. So basically, reversing the order will provide the solution I need.

Comment: Still resulting in the reversed order of the needed output.

Comment: Can you check it now? if does not work ,please tell me the input tables and the output table

Comment: Incorrect output after the last edit,the error occurs when a comparison is made between the views. Okay, how do I send the tables to you?

Comment: Actually, dont worry, I can reverse the order of the sql results (from your previous solution) in php , so it isnt a problem. Thanks for the solution. Perhaps you could republish the initial one, so that me marking this as a 'solution' doesnt seem more absurd than it already is.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this with `union` or `union all`.  Perhaps the following does what you want:

```
(SELECT TargetID as ContentId, TargetClass
 FROM Comments
 GROUP BY TargetID, TargetClass
 ORDER COUNT(*) DESC
 LIMIT 1
)
UNION ALL
(SELECT ContentID, Format
 FROM CONTENT
 GROUP BY ContentID, Format
 ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
 LIMIT 1
)
UNION ALL
(SELECT ContentID, Format
 FROM Likes
 GROUP BY ContentID, Format
 ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
 LIMIT 1
)
```

Comment: It will just output merged results from 3 tables but it won't produce the articles that have the most number of views, comments and likes. They should be `JOIN` ed by their IDs...

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'COUNT(TargetID) DESC LIMIT 1 ) UNION ALL (SELECT ContentID, Format FROM C' at line 4

That's the error I received when I tried to execute your solution.

Comment: @Sev . . . I assumed the original three queries were syntactically correct.  `count(*)` should do what you want.

Comment: The original three queries ran perfectly individually.

Comment: maybe this could alias TargetID to ContentID as it is treats the same and the final result will then have 2 columns instead of 3